# How to define interactive function that will not auto-complete?

Tags: completion, minibuffer, defun

If I do this:

```
(defun foo-bar-baz ()
  (interactive)
  (message "foo-bar-baz"))
```

And then `M-x foo-baz RET` (note no "bar") then completion matches `foo-bar-baz` and it executes.

Is there a way to define a function so as to prevent completion from considering it?

Comment: Not that I know of. This is the reason, BTW, that Emacs defines some Info commands with prefix `Info-` and others with prefix `info-`. (Similarly for some other (old) Emacs command names.)

Comment: Just curiosity on my part: why would you want that?